# How do to a custom text and photo field in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding wordpress templemate with bootstrap.

1. I want to code a row.
2. In this row are three pictures and under picture should be two text.

Everything I want then to edit in wordpress personalisation. Can you help me how I can do it?

The following is an illustration of the expected output:

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

You just create new Wordpress page template and put this html into it.
And then you'll have to create Theme Settings page which will be accessible from admin panel and you can put options controlling behavior and design of your code there.